# Functional analysis - discrete metric

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let Y denote any set. Let the discrete metric be defined as
$$d(x,x) = 0, \; d(x,y) = 1 \; if \; x \neq y.$$

(1) What is the completion of the discrete metric space?

- I have shown that Y is complete since all Cauchy sequences converge. However, I'm not sure if I can then say that Y is its own completion?

(2) What is the topology on Y induced by the metric?

- My intuition says that the topology is the empty set, one point, and the entire set Y. My question is whether this is true and if so how I can prove it?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What does "the metric space is closed" mean?

Comment: Yeah, that's my mistake I meant that Y is complete, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Because you have shown that all Cauchy sequences converge (which is correct) you can conclude that $Y$ is complete and therefore is its own completion.

(2) Look up "discrete topology".
To point out why your inutition is wrong in that case: Which point $y$ should you choose as the "special" point such that $\{y\}$ is open? Why is it "special" compared to other points $x$ (assuming $Y$ contains at least 2 elements)? But it is not entirely wrong: For *any* $y\in{Y}$, the set $\{y\}$ is open (can you proof that?). What does that mean for the induced topology on $Y$?